# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: curl

Please help me to overcome from this error. The response is bad request.

```
:~$ curl -sSik 'https://akab-dgggccicvhi6p7p5-5rjdbjpqquwl5gwz.luna.akamaiapis.net/config-media-live/v1/live/{abcdefgh-lh.akamaihd.net}/stream'
```

The response was:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 457
Date: Fri, 03 Oct 2014 05:40:02 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/problem+json

{
  "type": "https://problems.luna.akamaiapis.net/-/pep-authn/request-error",
  "title": "Bad request",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "Authorization header missing",
  .....
  "method": "GET",
  ....
  ....
  ....
  ....
  "requestTime": "2014-10-03T05:40:02Z"
}
```

Comment: Tried with this pattern:
curl --user name:password <put your address here> 
, are  you authorized on those resources?

Answer (score 2):

You are not correctly authorized to use the API.  Read the [API docs](https://developer.akamai.com/api/luna/config-media-live/overview.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Are you authorized on those resources? If not use [login and password](https://everything.curl.dev/http/auth).

To tell curl to do an authenticated HTTP request, you use the `-u`, `--user` option to provide user name and password (separated with a colon)

Example:

```
 curl --user name:password <url>
```